# Is the jQuery change() supposed to behave like that?

Tags: jquery, html

I have those two html radio buttons and textarea. I basically want to enable the textarea when Yes is selected, and disable it otherwise.

```
<input type='radio' id='comment' name='comment' value='Yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' id='comment' name='comment' value='No' checked="checked">No

<textarea id='writehere' name='writehere' cols='25' rows='2'></textarea>
```

Below is my jQuery. The commands only occur when I put it back to value No. But I want those commands to be executed everytime the "comment" is changed, regardless of Yes or No.

```
$('#writehere').attr('disabled','disabled');

$('#comment').change(function(){
        if ($('#comment').val() == 'No')
            $('#writehere').attr('disabled','disabled');

        if ($('#comment').val() == 'Yes')
            $('#writehere').removeAttr('disabled');

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 2 id that are the same that's your problem.

It's not W3C valid and in those situation jQuery will only proceed the first id.

Comment: Oh... thanks a lot for that. it was a class before and I change it quickly wihtout thinking. Thanks a lot. Regards

Comment: Sure glad to help you can get the elts with the name as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct usage of [jQuery's change](http://api.jquery.com/change/). However, you are violating an HTML rule in that you have two elements with the same id. Perhaps you could change it to this:

```
<input type='radio' class='comment-handler' name='comment' value='Yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' class='comment-handler' name='comment' value='No' checked="checked">No

$('.comment-handler').change(function(){
    if ($('.comment-handler').val() == 'No')
        $('#writehere').attr('disabled','disabled');

    if ($('.comment-handler').val() == 'Yes')
        $('#writehere').removeAttr('disabled');

    });
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks a lot for your response. Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should get the correct value:

```
$('input:radio[name=comment]:checked').val()
```

Since several elements have the same class and name, you should use `:checked` to get the `val()` from the correct element.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I never thought of the ":checked". Thanks for the tip. Regards